# Add field to label in highlights panel

Tags: page-layout, compact-layout, highlights-panel

I have a custom object 'Recipient' with a custom field to include last name. I need to display both the recipient's first **and** last name in the label portion of the highlights panel - right now, it only displays the 'Name' field which only shows the recipient's first name.

[image]

How can I achieve this? I already added 'Last_Name__c" to the compact layout - however it only shows the last name in the bottom half of the highlights panel and not the **label** of which is just 'John' right now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to add two separate fields to the top portion. You should create a formula field (if you haven't already) that combines the two fields, and then make that the first field in the compact layout.

Example:

```
Name = first name field
Last_Name__c = last name field
Full_Name__c = full name formula field

Full_Name__c = Name + ' ' + Last_Name__c

Set Full_Name__c as the compact layout's first field.
```

Edit: Added example.